# How to query Foobar to retrieve songs having length = mm:ss?

Tags: foobar2000

Is there a way to search in Foobar for files having length, lets's say, 3:05 [min:sec]?
Thanks.

Comment: Will have to look into search options, but why not add a length column and sort by that?

Answer (score 2):

In any search field (Ctrl+F or Media Library search), type `%length% EQUAL 185` (in seconds). You can also use the `GREATER` or `LESS` keywords instead of `EQUAL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%length_seconds%` and then keep working with that.

Example: I use this query to show all songs longer than 20 minutes (all the live- and dj-sets):

```
%length seconds% GREATER 900
```